# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ModuleLayer

Tags: java, console-application

I'm exporting an .jar file into an .exe file, it's a console application and the command line should appears on clicking.

But I'm getting this error and dont know how to find the solution, I'm using exe4j.

Does it needs a lib or an option that I've missed?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ModuleLayer
    at com.exe4j.runtime.jpms.ModuleHandler.findClass(ModuleHandler.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:79)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ModuleLayer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Do you have a manifest file? What is the command line?

Comment: What version of Java are you running on?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I was using Java 1.8, but due to this issue I've upgraded to Java 9.0.4

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax I dont have a manifest file. Im not sure about your second question, do you want to know what commands the program should execute?

Comment: What tool are you using to export jar into an exe. Also have you tried to add your jar  to CALSSPATH enviroment variables?

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax  I'm using exe4j

Comment: Have you tried to put the jar in eviroment variables. I also have a jar registered as a service on windows and got a similar type of error. Let me know if you find a solution.